# Making Sense of Nonsense: [Corner/Quine] Quotes!

Tags: philosophy-of-language, generative-grammar

Currently working on a problem set where we are using quine quotes (corner quotes) and normal quotes to distinguish use and mention. In class I felt that examples were much simpler, both of these sentences have features that are just incomprehensible to me and I was hoping for some guidance.

**Note: I'm looking for more than just answers to these two problems but to really understand this stuff so if you have any helpful resources, tips, etc. please include them in your answer!**

If  the  sentence  is  as  it  stands  false  or  senseless,  change  it  to  a  true  sentence by supplying quotes and/or corner quotes, or explain why no such alteration is possible.

A) For every sentence φ, the last word of the last word of φ is polysyllabic is polysyllabic.

In this sentence, the two repeated phrases "the last word" and "is polysyllabic" throw me, I just don't see how they can be incorporated. No variation of use or mention makes the last word of a last word of phi make sense-- and the double polysyllabic? I'm at a total loss.

B) The first letter of the Greek alphabet is α is satisfied by an object β only if β is identical with α.

This one is even more frustrating, it seems that there is an α missing and it should read: [...]alphabet is α, α is satisfied.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Quote marks can show the structure. (A) _For every sentence φ, the last word of "the last word of φ is polysyllabic" is polysyllabic_. (B) _"The first letter of the Greek alphabet is α" is satisfied by an object β only if β is identical with α_.

Comment: @jlawler A total lifesaver! Those were actually exceedingly simple, guess I stared at them too long and just needed a fresh set of eyes. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it would be better suited to the [puzzling.se] site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For every sentence φ, the last word of "the last word of φ is polysyllabic" is "polysyllabic".

Or, since "polysyllabic" is polysyllabic,

> For every sentence φ, the last word of "the last word of φ is polysyllabic" is polysyllabic.

and

> "The first letter of the Greek alphabet is α" is satisfied by an object β only if β is identical with "α".